NIKON kit lens - lens clicking as camera is turned on, even when VR turned off
I've not used my DSLR camera for a while. I just took it out for a few days and it is consistently exhibiting the following behaviour:

Look through the viewfinder
Turn the camera on
There's four clicks/clacks, and the image in the viewfinder bounces up and down in sync with it

If I turn the camera on and half-depress the shutter button then I can interrupt the clacks, but it's likely to do it later instead.
At first, I thought it might be the mirror adjusting for some reason. But, based on an answer to a different question, I've realised that it's the lens (Nikkor AF-S 18-200mm kit lens) rather than the camera body. However, setting VR to Off doesn't fix it, and setting VR to Off and setting the upper switch to M (instead of M/A) just makes it clack twice instead of four times. If I swap in my 85mm lens then there's no unusual behaviour.
I'm not noticing any issues of VR not working, just the noise when I turn it on.
Is this a known problem? Is there a fix, or do I just need a new lens?

How long was the camera sitting? Any noticeable issues with the lens? Its contacts clean? Nothing looks bent, damaged, or out of place?

Based on the photos on the camera, it wasn't used for a couple of years. It was stored in a padded camera bag in a home office. There's no obvious issues with the lens, and the photos that I've taken are all fine. Contacts appear to be clean, and the other lens doesn't exhibit any problems.

I assume the 85 mm doesn’t have VR. Is it possible that this is normal behavior but given the camera set for so long it feels new? I am rather stumped.

No, the 85mm lens has VR (https://www.nikon.co.uk/en_GB/product/lenses/dslr/af-s-dx-micro-nikkor-85mm-f3.5g-ed-vr). It's not got an active mode, but it's got VR.
And I'm about as certain as I can be that it's new behaviour. It's possible that I missed the image shift before, but not the clunking from the lens.
